# Gain focus in editext

Tags: android, layout

I have an edit text like this below. The problem is my edit text is not having the blinking cursor. How can I get this? Specifically, what I want is when the user clicks on my Edit Text once, the keyboard  should come up. Any idea how I can do this?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="1" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: just add <requestFocus/> in ur edittext

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for gain focus.

```
EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.requestFocus();
editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom the blinking cursor will show automatic when the EditText get the focus, I think if there is something else vie the focus, so your EditText can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<requestFocus />` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="1" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener()` and override the listener's `onFocusChange`:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // come up with the keyboard.
            }

        }
    });
```

if you want the `EditText` to gain the focus, call `requestFocus()`

Answer (score 0):

To open the keyboard implicitly. use this

```
// for showing the soft keyboard on click of edit text
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService   (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
    mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and to have the cursor visible just add this in your xml.

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

Good Luck!..